# Google Script reject to insert Google link as link @ google docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Can you please give me a solution or other way to deal with to make a google doc link work on the alert message or through sidebar in HTML link, I get Malformed HTML conten Error and if I replace by regular link which such as www.google.com it work find.

Here the error massage look like 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yHcX.png)

That full details :

> Malformed HTML content: hi byehttps://docs.google.com/open?id=185g8pZGceMlIqmhEsYV8tkfxKsiRd_P3t3mhjzLiX0Y
>   target=_blank > test 
>  http://www.google.com>.

**My code is the following :**

```
function test0001()
{

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); 
  var docurl = doc.getUrl(); 

  //var x = Gconvertlinko() ;
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('hi '+ 'bye' + "<a href="+ docurl+"  target=_blank > test </a>"+ "<br/> <input type="+' text'+" name="+ 'lname'+ "  value="+ "http://www.google.com" +">")
  /*.setContent( DocumentApp.getActiveDocument.getUrl() + "<br/>"+ DocumentApp.getActiveDocument.getUrl() ) */
      .setTitle('Google Convertor');

  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);


}
```

Please let me know if you got any idea or thought to deal with that .

Answer (score 1):

Your `docurl` variable has an equal sign which is causing this. In the end your `<a>` tag would have the property `href=https://docs.google.com/open?id=185g8pZGceMlIqmhEsYV8tkfxKsiRd_P3t3mhjzLiX0Y`. Notice that there are two equal signs which is invalid syntax.

To solve this simply put single quotes aroud the docurl:

```
ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('hi '+ 'bye' + "<a href='"+ docurl+"'  target=_blank > test </a>"+ "<br/> <input type="+' text'+" name="+ 'lname'+ "  value="+ "http://www.google.com" +">")
```

Comment: Thank you for declaring situation, it starts working.